# Decrease an INT by 10% each round in C

Tags: c, loops

How can I decrease an int (used for my delay time) by 10% each time?
Here is my current concept I would like to improve this.

```
void lights()
{
    light1(on);
    delay(50000);
    light1(off);
    delay(50000);
    light2(on);
    delay(50000);
    light2(off);
    delay(50000);

    light1(on);
    delay(40000);
    light1(off);
    delay(40000);
    light2(on);
    delay(40000);
    light2(off);
    delay(40000);

    delay(30000);
    delay(20000);
    delay(10000);
    delay(9000);
    delay(8000);
    all the way to like delay(100);
}
```

After each lights on/off cycle it can decrease the delay by 10%.
I'm not sure how to go about this I tried googling and I think I've seen something similar in python but I don't understand it enough to convert to C.

My unfinished idea:

```
void lights()
{
    int delayTime = 0;

    for (int i = 0; /* decrease delayTime by 10% */ )
    {

        light1(on);
        delay(delayTime);
        light1(off);
        delay(delayTime);
        light2(on);
        delay(delayTime);
        light2(off);
        delay(delayTime);

        if (delayTime <= 100)
        {
            // Done end of method/function
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `delayTime*9/10` or `delayTime - delayTime/10`

Comment: It seems like you need to do some more tutorials...

Comment: Yes, the answer below was perfect, I'm glad how it was explained.
Now i'm off to do some C math tutorials x.x Thanks all!

Comment: Is this not just a primary-school arithmetic question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three statements after `for` are the initialization, the test condition for continuing the loop, and the statement repeated on each loop. We want to initialize `delayTime` to 50,000. We want to continue if `delayTime` is greater than or equal to 100. And we want to multiply it by 0.9 each loop (preferably without doing any floating point math). So:

```
for (delayTime = 50000;
    delayTime >= 100;
    delayTime -= delayTime / 10)
{

    light1(on);
    delay(delayTime);
    light1(off);
    delay(delayTime);
    light2(on);
    delay(delayTime);
    light2(off);
    delay(delayTime);
}
```